# Access Denied when trying to check is Shopify Payments is activated

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to check whether the merchant has enabled Shopify Payments or not. For this purpose, i feel that the following GraphQL query would work:

```
query {
   shopifyPaymentsAccount{
      activated
   }
}
```

But this query is giving the following error:

`Error: GraphQL error: Access denied for shopifyPaymentsAccount field. Required access: User must have given access.`

Note: it has been copied exactly as is. There is nothing after `Required Access:` .

For which scope do I have to request the permission for this to work? Or what would be a better way to check if Shopify Payments is activated?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hey, i dont remember the fix exactly... but maybe it was due to the api version